# Converting Decimal number to 10's complement

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there any other way to convert a decimal number to 10's complement without substraction?
Not this method:

```
Converting 052784:
100000-052784 = 947216
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no: the fact that subtraction is involved is suggested by the word "complement".

The usual procedure is to ignore any leading zeros, subtract the lowest-order non-zero digit
from 10 and all the remaining digits from 9.

Addition and subtraction are computationally fast compared to other operations. As you can see in your example, one measly subtraction (that takes about a billionth of a second in a computer) and you're finished.